# How to retrieve specific data from Firestore Database?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to find the mobile number of a user from the Firestore database which has all the user details after checking a condition which says if the flat and the block number of the user matches with the entry in flat and block than retrieve his mobile number.

The image shows the screenshot of database.
[image]

Comment: I'm not very clear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **almost 450 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Yes thanks for your suggestion. I will send the minimum possible code and redefine my problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, try something like this:

```
 FirebaseFirestore  fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        final String[] requiredMobile = {""}; //this is up to how you want to use the mobile number acquired
        fireStore.collection("users").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot document: documentSnapshot.getDocuments()
                     ) {
                    if(document.getString("flat")== ("desired Flat") && document.getString("block") =="desired blockNumber"){
                        requiredMobile[0] = document.getString("mobile"); //do something with phone number
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you send the correct syntax for the above code please..Seems like it will work for me but once the syntax is right

Comment: I am getting null value of the mobile using the code and I don't need an array I just want one mobile number in String format which matches with the flat and block of the user.

Comment: I have added the complete code to check and identify why it is giving null value. The corresponding value from the Firebase database should be thrown.

Comment: You dont need to use the array just get the value you want. Dont follow the code letter for letter, tweak it to suit your scenario

Comment: I even used getData instead of getString but unfortunately the value is still null and the call is sent to null...please suggest

Comment: i have ammended the code, pleace change ```for (DocumentSnapshot document: documentSnapshot``` to ```for (DocumentSnapshot document: documentSnapshot.getDocuments()```

Comment: Tried using that as well but nothing happens. I have separated the code which has issues. Can you please suggest  what is stopping the value retrieval and the call function.

Comment: Can anyone please help...need the solution urgently